# how to show the socket id in 'connection' callback

Tags: socket.io-1.0

I tried to use official demo in socket.io. 
In this demo, it gives two arguments for connection callback.first is id,second is msg.but actually in `function(id, msg)`, i tried and find out that the id is still the message,not id actually. why?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: A socket id for a receiving socket is in `socket.id`.  It's not passed with the message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem myself. if we use `to(<socketid>)`, this cannot go to socket itself. have to go to other sockets.